# Multithreaded Python program starting multiple processes

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, htop

This simple Python program :

```
import threading
import time
import os

def run_test():

    print("run_test pid : " + str(os.getpid()))

    while True:
        time.sleep(100)

print("main pid : " + str(os.getpid()))
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=run_test)
thread1.start()
```

Starts multiple processes according to htop:

[image]

With PIDs 12004 and 12040.

However, there doesn't appear to be any point in the program where the second process is created.

Where does the  second process come from ?

Comment: Which version of Python are you running? The code only shows one process when I run it on 2.7.10

Comment: I'm running Python3.5

Comment: This process runs forever... sure you don't have an old one running along with the new one?

Comment: If you haven't tried already, i would kill all of the processes in question and test it again...

Comment: yep, pretty damn sure

Comment: How about getting the process tree or at least the ppid, say, `ps  xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm`. Also, ctrl-c the program and restart it. Is the 12004 process still there?   ... and cut and paste to post so we don't have to squint at the screenshot.

Comment: Apparently it is due to the fact that vanilla htop doesn't distinguish between process identifiers and thread identifiers without activating options ( source : my roommate )

Comment: Yup!  @Kalessar nailed it.  See here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps